# Why I am not getting string correct label to python dataframe with timeseries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement, label

I want to label each value in data frame, if there is *zero* then label with **GND** and *not zero* then name **Dry** but I am receiving only **GND** label to whole data frame.

```
result:

Timestamp   Dryer_power Label

2012-06-01 00:33:37 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:38 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:39 2.1906  GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:40 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:41 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:42 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:43 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:44 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:45 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:46 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:47 2.1906  GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:48 0.0 GND,
2012-06-01 00:33:49 0.0 GND,

for i in df['Dryer_power'].iloc[:]:
    if(i == float(0)):
         df['Label'] = 'GND,'
    else:
         df['Label'] = 'Dry, '
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Try:

```
import numpy as np

df['Label'] = np.where(df['Dryer_power'].eq(0.0), 'GND,', 'Dry,')
```

If that still doesnt work try:

```
df['Label'] = np.NaN #this creates an empty column
```

first, followed by my previous statement. But you shouldn't have to use it.

Comment: Good answer. (Also, `np.where` should be named `np.ifthenelse`.)

Comment: No, I am getting key error: _Label_  beacause I think _Label_ column does not exist in data frame **df**

Comment: exactly, your question looks clearer now, I made a change to my answer.

Comment: I added empty column with: df["Label"] = "" but, It gives me all label as **Dry**

Comment: It should work without the need to create an empty column, it didn't work just now because I was passing the "Label" column into the np.where (which didn't exist - couldn't see your question properly until you reformatted it), now I'm passing an existing column.

Comment: dont use your code first, try to create the dataframe as you did previously (without a label column), and try using my first code again.

Comment: I could not find **_np.ifthenelse_** this attribute.

Comment: that was a joke it doesnt exist, please also ```import numpy as np``` and then, please try ```df['Label'] = np.where(df['Dryer_power'].eq(0.0), 'GND,', 'Dry,')```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `for` loops in pandas dataframes. Its inefficient when the dataframe size is huge. Instead you should use `map`:-

```
df["Label"] = df["Dryer_power"].map(lambda x: "GND," if x==0.0 else "Dry, ")
```

This will solve the problem.

Comment: This works perfectly. _Thank you for all to give quick response_.